# Como fazer lembretes CSS ao passar o cursor do mouse?

Tags: css

Como faço para exbir um `tooltip` ao passar o cursor do mouse sobre o ícone de interrogação ?

Veja o exemplo na figura abaixo :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você também pode visualizar o exemplo clicando [aqui](http://imobex.com.br/planos.php).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [É possível fazer um tooltip com CSS puro?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101968/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Olá, não há nada de duplicado, pois não estou perguntando como fazer um TOOLTIP. A indagação que faço é outra, leia e entenda o texto.

Comment: Reverti a pergunta, pois mudou completamente o sentido da original, e invalidou as respostas existentes. Se tem nova dúvida, faça em separado.

Comment: Depois da edição o sentido mudou totalmente, até então duplicata sim, não tem porque ser agressivo argumentando leia "entenda o texto". Recomendo que seja compreensivo e se discorda apenas comente **"não é isso o que preciso, o que preciso é isso ..."**. Ok? não tinha nada na pergunta original falando do posicionamento. Obrigado por compreender e recomendo que leia o link [seja respeitoso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) =)

Answer (score 7):

Para mostrar um elemento "flutuante" no *mouseover*:

```css
.hm div {display:none;position:relative}
.hm:hover div {display:block;position:absolute;top:0;margin-left:40px}

/* daqui pra baixo é só estética para demonstração */
.hm {
  width:1.5em;height:1.5em;
  text-align:center;
  font:20px/1.5em "segoe ui",arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  border:1px solid #999;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#999;
}

.hm div {
  width:8em;
  color:#fff;
  background:#999;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hm">?<div>Batatinha quando nasce esparrama pelo chão.</div></div>
```

O importante está nas duas primeiras linhas do CSS.

Pra formatar o balão como no exemplo dado, aqui já tem a solução:

> [Botões pontudos e Balões de Texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30134/70)

<sub>Só de curiosidade, eu escolhi a frase acima pq eu gosto dela exatamente como está. Mas se tiver algum erro especificamente de **ortografia**, me avisem.</sub>

<sub>**esparramar**</sub>
<sub>es.par.ra.mar</sub>
<sub>(es+parra+(ra)ma+ar2) vtd 1 Dispersar, espalhar, esparralhar. vint e vpr 2 Dispersar-se, espalhar-se</sub>

Answer (score 3):

```css
.wrapper {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #ececec;
  color: #555;
  cursor: help;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 100px 75px 10px 75px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

.wrapper .tooltip {
  background: #1496bb;
  bottom: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  left: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
       -o-transform: translateY(10px);
          transform: translateY(10px);
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
          transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
       -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.wrapper .tooltip:before {
  bottom: -20px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}  

/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.wrapper .tooltip:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
}
  
.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
       -o-transform: translateY(0px);
          transform: translateY(0px);
}

/* IE can just show/hide with no transition */
.lte8 .wrapper .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.lte8 .wrapper:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- normally this stuff would be on the html element -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>  <div class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <div class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <div class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <div class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <div> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <div>             <!--<![endif]-->
  <div class="wrapper">
    I have a tooltip.
    <div class="tooltip">I am a tooltip!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Original: http://jsfiddle.net/raving/87865bq7/

Se quer algo minimalista:

```css
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
 
    /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Original: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp