# Como fazer a ponta do "balão de dialogo"?

Tags: html, css

Como faço esse triangulo antes da aba dos números?
Tem como fazer isso manipulando as bordas?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, e você precisa de um elemento separado só para a seta. Por exemplo, usando um `<div>`:

```css
div {
    width: 12px;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #f4bb00;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Leia [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2396/74) para os detalhes sobre como funciona a manipulação de bordas para produzir triângulos.

Comment: +1 e esse "elemento separado" poderia ser um `:before` criado no CSS (caso se queira incluir a seta em vários botões, sem ficar criando elementos adicionais).

Comment: Sim, pode ser um :before