# Opacidade em Pseudo-Element e Parent

Tags: html, css

Eu quero fazer uma `div` com o canto esquerdo inclinado, mas não está dando certo.

Esse é o jeito certo de fazer ?

No meu caso até funciona porquê a `div` pai tem `overflow`, então nem aparece o resto do `:before` em baixo.

O problema nisso é a opacidade, fica com o `:before` atrás **visível**, por assim dizer.

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

h4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -41px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  bottom: -7px;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<h4> Aqui vai uma frase </h4>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi bem o seu objetivo, uma das maneiras é usar o [truque dos triângulos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2396):

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

h4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<h4> Aqui vai uma frase </h4>
```

Comment: Usei seu jeito. Legal. Não sabia disso, na verdade nem enxerguei triângulo nisso. Mas lendo a matéria no LINK entendi.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar o atributo `border-radius` no seu CSS. Veja a referência no [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp)

Para resolver o problema da opacidade você ajusta a cor da div até que ela fique igual a outra cor sem opacidade. Ou simplesmente tira a opacidade das duas e ajusta a cor no atributo `rgba(248, 149, 32, 1);`

```css
h4 {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: rgba(248, 149, 32, 0.8);
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  height: 34px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: rgba(248, 171, 79,1);
  bottom: -7px;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<h4> Aqui vai uma frase </h4>
```

Note que para fazer a junção das duas DIVs eu modifiquei a posição alguns pixels.