# efeito triangulo em div com css3, tem como?

Tags: css3

queria saber se tem como deixar uma div parecido com esse efeito, se tiver como alguem pode dar um exemplo? nao tenho ideia de onde comecar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criar um triângulo com CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2394/criar-um-tri%c3%a2ngulo-com-css)

Comment: Bruno da pra fazer com bordas, clip-path, svg, linear-gradiente,  skwe, etc... da uma olhada, nessa resposta que eu marquei como duplicada

Comment: desculpa, mais e totalmente diferente do que eu espero

Comment: Não Bruno, é completamente igual a outra, só que em vez de usar o efeito em um retângulo na outra resposta foi usado em um quadrado, tanto que a resposta que deram aqui usa justamente as técnicas das bordas como mencionei, e que tb foi usada na outra resposta. Pelo visto vc nem se deu ao trabalho de ler a outra resposta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prontinho amigo, so ajustar os tamanhos dos border em questão...abçs

```css
 .lado1{
  
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 

  border-left: 280px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid #0EF41A;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="lado1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muito bom, vou fazer os testes aqui

Comment: peço que de um ticket de correto se tiver respondido a sua pergunta

Comment: na verdade, eu precisaria que isso nao tivesse um widtth definido, pois minha intenção é fazer um slide de volume, isso diminuiria e aumentaria o tamanho, entendeu ?, tentei usar `border-left-width` mais não deu certo

Comment: o que vai definir nao é o width e sim o border-left, o width é zero!